# rails managing secret_token and git pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been messing with rails for awhile now, but I just started dabbling with git repository and I have a question regarding rails secret_token. I'm using figaro to help secure my secret keys so when I push to the repository, the sensitive keys won't be uploaded as well.

Now when I use another computer to pull the files from the master branch, the secret_token won't be there... Is it important to use the same secret token? Or can I just use `rake secret` to just get a new generated token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' `secret_token` is used for:

1. `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`
2. HTTP Basic and Digest Access Authentication

So for most cases it should be fine to just generate a new one with `rake secret` on different machines. As long as your configuration keeps the same one for all instances in your deployment.